# Titanium Studio wont load any emulators, returns errors upon starting

Tags: node.js, installation, titanium, java-6

I have recently installed Titanium Studio. Upon opening the program i get the error

```
"An internal error occurred during: "Computing SDK Info...".
java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

If i attempt to create a new emulator i get the error:

```
"An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing provisioning information...".
java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

Ive seen this question a million times but I cant get anything to work. I uninstalled and reinstalled node. I heard Titanium Studio wasnt working with node v12 so i went back to 0.10. I uninstalled and reinstalled java i reinstalled the java sdk i re installed the android sdk, i have attempted to "sudo npm install titanium -g" about 50 times and it always returns

```
Users/admin/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/ti ->       /Users/admin/.nvm/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/titanium/bin/titanium
/Users/admin/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/titanium ->    /Users/admin/.nvm/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/titanium/bin/titanium
titanium@3.4.1 /Users/admin/.nvm/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/titanium
├── sprintf@0.1.5
├── colors@0.6.2
├── longjohn@0.2.4
├── humanize@0.0.9
├── async@0.2.10
├── wrench@1.5.8
├── semver@2.2.1
├── fields@0.1.23 (keypress@0.2.1)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── temp@0.6.0 (osenv@0.0.3, rimraf@2.1.4)
├── winston@0.6.2 (cycle@1.0.3, stack-trace@0.0.9, eyes@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.2.3,  async@0.1.22, request@2.9.203)
├── request@2.27.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, aws-sign@0.3.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, qs@0.6.6, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, oauth-sign@0.3.0, cookie-jar@0.3.0, mime@1.2.11, node-uuid@1.4.2, form-data@0.1.4, hawk@1.0.0, http-signature@0.10.1)
├── moment@2.4.0
├── jade@0.35.0 (character-parser@1.2.0, commander@2.0.0, mkdirp@0.3.5,    with@1.1.1, transformers@2.1.0, constantinople@1.0.2, monocle@1.1.50)
└── node-appc@0.2.14 (diff@1.0.8, node-uuid@1.4.2, xmldom@0.1.19, semver@2.1.0,       adm-zip@0.4.7, dox@0.4.6, uglify-js@2.3.6)
```

running "ti info" returns

```
 |[ERROR] Failed to run command "info"
   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/longjohn/dist/longjohn.js:185
        throw e;
              ^
    logger.log (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/logger.js:72:21),target.     (anonymous function) [as error]    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/common.js:4    5:21),CLI.<anonymous>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/cli.js:955:17),/usr/local/lib/node_modul    es/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:119:25,Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:24:16),CLI._    fireHookCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:269:12),/usr/local/lib/node_modu  les/titanium/lib/hook.js:248:10,/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/  async/lib/async.js:232:13,async.eachSeries  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:130:20)"
```

and "check" ing titanium in setup gives me this information:

```
Check Environment 
Node.js
✓  node               up-to-date (v0.12.0)
★  npm                new version v2.6.1 available! (currently v2.5.1)

Titanium CLI
✓  cli                up-to-date (v3.4.1)

Titanium CLI Dependencies
 ✓  async              up-to-date (v0.2.10)
 ✓  colors             up-to-date (v0.6.2)
 ✓  fields             up-to-date (v0.1.23)
 ✓  humanize           up-to-date (v0.0.9)
 ✓  jade               up-to-date (v0.35.0)
 ✓  longjohn           up-to-date (v0.2.4)
 ✓  moment             up-to-date (v2.4.0)
 ✓  node-appc          up-to-date (v0.2.14)
 ✓  optimist           up-to-date (v0.6.1)
 ✓  request            up-to-date (v2.27.0)
 ✓  semver             up-to-date (v2.2.1)
 ✓  sprintf            up-to-date (v0.1.5)
 ✓  temp               up-to-date (v0.6.0)
 ✓  winston            up-to-date (v0.6.2)
 ✓  wrench             up-to-date (v1.5.8)

Titanium SDK
 ✓  latest sdk         installed (v3.5.0.GA)
 ✕  selected sdk       selected Titanium SDK "vundefined" is not installed

Mac OS X Environment
 ✓  CLI Tools          installed

iOS Environment
 ✓  Xcode              installed (6.1.1)
 ✓  iOS SDK            installed (8.1)
 ✓  WWDR cert          installed
 !  developer cert     not found
 !  distribution cert  not found
 !  dev provisioning   not found
 !  dist provisioning  not found

Android Environment
 !  sdk                Android SDK not found
 !  targets            no targets found
 !  avds               no avds found
 ✓  ndk                installed (undefined)
 ✓  ndk-build          installed (undefined)

Java Development Kit
 ✕  jdk                JDK not found!

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
 ✓  compatible
 ✓  installed

Network
 ✓  online
 -  no proxy server configured
 ✓  http request test
 ✓  https request test

Directory Permissions
 ✓  home directory
 ✓  titanium config directory
 ✓  titanium sdk install directory
 ✓  temp directory"
```

I have tried deleting my config.json file and letting Titanium recreate it and setting the properties in the cli but absolutely nothing changes these errors. I am really at my wits end here. I really really need some kind of help so if anybody please knows how to just make Titanium Studio work I would be so grateful, Ive been trying for days...

Comment: With the info you provided, it shows **JDK not found!**, it could be the error or jdk is not in global environment. Btw titanium requires jdk >= 1.6, [more here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Prerequisites-section-29004873_Prerequisites-JavaDevelopmentKit) .

Comment: I was able to properly reset node to 0.10.35 which clears up the JDK not found error in Titanium set up but still returns the exact same java nullpointerexception when i load up Titanium Studio and gives same errors when trying to make an emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually downgrade Node correctly? In your log above I see:

```
✓  node               up-to-date (v0.12.0)
```

*(Should be 0.10.35)*

Have you tried running `titanium sdk select [version]` ?

Comment: I was able to correctly set node to 0.10.35 but its returning the same error.
The only Titanium SDK i have installed to choose from is 3.5.0.GA. Should i be looking for another Titanium SDK? Im still getting the JAVA null pointer exception upon starting the application. 
     Node.js
     ★  node               new version v0.12.0 available! (currently v0.10.35)
     ★  npm                new version v2.6.1 available! (currently v1.4.28)

Everything under set up now gets a green check mark except for the last 4 things under iOS Environment and "tools" under Android Environment which is untested

Comment: Does it let you select 3.5.0.GA? You don't need to look for another, but it says you have no selected version. Try and set it and let me know what happens. titanium sdk select 3.5.0.GA in terminal. Run the check again and update your Q with it, please.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me Peach. I was able to select the 3.5.0.GA but im still having the exact same errors. Still Cant locate JDK and still cant locate Android SDK. Still returning the java.lang.nullPointerException upon loading and when trying to create an ios emulator. When trying to create an Android emulator I cant click the device drop down menu. I dont know why it cant find my JDK..

Comment: Man, I've been googling this and looking over the forum. I'm glad you were able to select the right SDK but that error is obviously a pain. Here are a few threads I found from Appcelerator that might help, rather than me just relaying info:
https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/179951/an-internal-error-occurred-during-computing-sdk-info-javalangnullpointerexception
Second post here: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/178543/titanium-sdk--an-internal-error-occurred-during-computing-sdk-info-javalangnullpointerexception